# Getting started with secure AWS CloudFront streaming with Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have created a S3 bucket, uploaded a video, created a streaming distribution in CloudFront. Tested it with a static HTML player and it works. I have created a keypair through the account settings. I have the private key file sitting on my desktop at the moment. That's where I am.

My aim is to get to a point where my Django/Python site creates secure URLs and people can't access the videos unless they've come from one of my pages. The problem is I'm allergic to the way Amazon have laid things out and I'm just getting more and more confused.

I realise this isn't going to be the best question on StackOverflow but I'm certain I can't be the only fool out here that can't make heads or tails out of how to set up a secure CloudFront/S3 situation. I would really appreciate your help and am willing (once two days has passed) give a 500pt bounty to the best answer.

I have several questions that, once answered, should fit into one explanation of how to accomplish what I'm after:

- In the documentation (there's an example in the next point) there's lots of XML lying around telling me I need to `POST` things to various places. Is there an online console for doing this? Or do I literally have to force this up via cURL (et al)?
- How do I create a Origin Access Identity for CloudFront and bind it to my distribution? I've read [this document](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?SecuringContent_S3.html#CreateOriginAccessIdentity) but, per the first point, don't know what to do with it. How does my keypair fit into this?
- Once that's done, how do I limit the S3 bucket to only allow people to download things through that identity? If this is another XML jobby rather than clicking around the web UI, please tell me where and how I'm supposed to get this into my account.
- In Python, what's the easiest way of generating an expiring URL for a file. I have `boto` installed but I don't see how to get a file from a streaming distribution.
- Are there are any applications or scripts that can take the difficulty of setting this garb up? I use Ubuntu (Linux) but I have XP in a VM if it's Windows-only. I've already looked at CloudBerry S3 Explorer Pro - but it makes about as much sense as the online UI.

Comment: You mentioned in your Question that you used "a static HTML player" is this possible! I thought the only way to play the the rtmp is to use a Flash based player. please reply with the tutorial to do so if possible. Thanks

Comment: as quite a while passed after this question as well as the accepted answer, few things have changed. Boto3 is introduced. So, i detailed the process of signing URL from new Boto doc in my answer below. Sure, my answer will age, too

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You're right, it takes a lot of API work to get this set up.  I hope they get it in the AWS Console soon!

**UPDATE: I have submitted this code to boto - as of boto v2.1 (released 2011-10-27) this gets much easier.  For boto < 2.1, use the instructions here.  For boto 2.1 or greater, get the updated instructions on my blog: http://www.secretmike.com/2011/10/aws-cloudfront-secure-streaming.html  Once boto v2.1 gets packaged by more distros I'll update the answer here.**

To accomplish what you want you need to perform the following steps which I will detail below:

1. Create your s3 bucket and upload some objects (you've already done this)
2. Create a Cloudfront "Origin Access Identity" (basically an AWS account to allow cloudfront to access your s3 bucket)
3. Modify the ACLs on your objects so that only your Cloudfront Origin Access Identity is allowed to read them (this prevents people from bypassing Cloudfront and going direct to s3)
4. Create a cloudfront distribution with basic URLs and one which requires signed URLs
5. Test that you can download objects from basic cloudfront distribution but not from s3 or the signed cloudfront distribution
6. Create a key pair for signing URLs
7. Generate some URLs using Python
8. Test that the signed URLs work

---

**1 - Create Bucket and upload object**

The easiest way to do this is through the AWS Console but for completeness I'll show how using boto.  Boto code is shown here:

```
import boto

#credentials stored in environment AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
s3 = boto.connect_s3()

#bucket name MUST follow dns guidelines
new_bucket_name = "stream.example.com"
bucket = s3.create_bucket(new_bucket_name)

object_name = "video.mp4"
key = bucket.new_key(object_name)
key.set_contents_from_filename(object_name)
```

**2 - Create a Cloudfront "Origin Access Identity"**

For now, this step can only be performed using the API.  Boto code is here:

```
import boto

#credentials stored in environment AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
cf = boto.connect_cloudfront()

oai = cf.create_origin_access_identity(comment='New identity for secure videos')

#We need the following two values for later steps:
print("Origin Access Identity ID: %s" % oai.id)
print("Origin Access Identity S3CanonicalUserId: %s" % oai.s3_user_id)
```

**3 - Modify the ACLs on your objects**

Now that we've got our special S3 user account (the S3CanonicalUserId we created above) we need to give it access to our s3 objects.  We can do this easily using the AWS Console by opening the object's (not the bucket's!) Permissions tab, click the "Add more permissions" button, and pasting the very long S3CanonicalUserId we got above into the "Grantee" field of a new.  Make sure you give the new permission "Open/Download" rights.

You can also do this in code using the following boto script:

```
import boto

#credentials stored in environment AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
s3 = boto.connect_s3()

bucket_name = "stream.example.com"
bucket = s3.get_bucket(bucket_name)

object_name = "video.mp4"
key = bucket.get_key(object_name)

#Now add read permission to our new s3 account
s3_canonical_user_id = "<your S3CanonicalUserID from above>"
key.add_user_grant("READ", s3_canonical_user_id)
```

**4 - Create a cloudfront distribution**

Note that custom origins and private distributions are not fully supported in boto until version 2.0 which has not been formally released at time of writing.  The code below pulls out some code from the boto 2.0 branch and hacks it together to get it going but it's not pretty.  The 2.0 branch handles this much more elegantly - definitely use that if possible!

```
import boto
from boto.cloudfront.distribution import DistributionConfig
from boto.cloudfront.exception import CloudFrontServerError

import re

def get_domain_from_xml(xml):
    results = re.findall("<DomainName>([^<]+)</DomainName>", xml)
    return results[0]

#custom class to hack this until boto v2.0 is released
class HackedStreamingDistributionConfig(DistributionConfig):

    def __init__(self, connection=None, origin='', enabled=False,
                 caller_reference='', cnames=None, comment='',
                 trusted_signers=None):
        DistributionConfig.__init__(self, connection=connection,
                                    origin=origin, enabled=enabled,
                                    caller_reference=caller_reference,
                                    cnames=cnames, comment=comment,
                                    trusted_signers=trusted_signers)

    #override the to_xml() function
    def to_xml(self):
        s = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n'
        s += '<StreamingDistributionConfig xmlns="http://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-07-15/">\n'

        s += '  <S3Origin>\n'
        s += '    <DNSName>%s</DNSName>\n' % self.origin
        if self.origin_access_identity:
            val = self.origin_access_identity
            s += '    <OriginAccessIdentity>origin-access-identity/cloudfront/%s</OriginAccessIdentity>\n' % val
        s += '  </S3Origin>\n'


        s += '  <CallerReference>%s</CallerReference>\n' % self.caller_reference
        for cname in self.cnames:
            s += '  <CNAME>%s</CNAME>\n' % cname
        if self.comment:
            s += '  <Comment>%s</Comment>\n' % self.comment
        s += '  <Enabled>'
        if self.enabled:
            s += 'true'
        else:
            s += 'false'
        s += '</Enabled>\n'
        if self.trusted_signers:
            s += '<TrustedSigners>\n'
            for signer in self.trusted_signers:
                if signer == 'Self':
                    s += '  <Self/>\n'
                else:
                    s += '  <AwsAccountNumber>%s</AwsAccountNumber>\n' % signer
            s += '</TrustedSigners>\n'
        if self.logging:
            s += '<Logging>\n'
            s += '  <Bucket>%s</Bucket>\n' % self.logging.bucket
            s += '  <Prefix>%s</Prefix>\n' % self.logging.prefix
            s += '</Logging>\n'
        s += '</StreamingDistributionConfig>\n'

        return s

    def create(self):
        response = self.connection.make_request('POST',
            '/%s/%s' % ("2010-11-01", "streaming-distribution"),
            {'Content-Type' : 'text/xml'},
            data=self.to_xml())

        body = response.read()
        if response.status == 201:
            return body
        else:
            raise CloudFrontServerError(response.status, response.reason, body)


cf = boto.connect_cloudfront()

s3_dns_name = "stream.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com"
comment = "example streaming distribution"
oai = "<OAI ID from step 2 above like E23KRHS6GDUF5L>"

#Create a distribution that does NOT need signed URLS
hsd = HackedStreamingDistributionConfig(connection=cf, origin=s3_dns_name, comment=comment, enabled=True)
hsd.origin_access_identity = oai
basic_dist = hsd.create()
print("Distribution with basic URLs: %s" % get_domain_from_xml(basic_dist))

#Create a distribution that DOES need signed URLS
hsd = HackedStreamingDistributionConfig(connection=cf, origin=s3_dns_name, comment=comment, enabled=True)
hsd.origin_access_identity = oai
#Add some required signers (Self means your own account)
hsd.trusted_signers = ['Self']
signed_dist = hsd.create()
print("Distribution with signed URLs: %s" % get_domain_from_xml(signed_dist))
```

**5 - Test that you can download objects from cloudfront but not from s3**

You should now be able to verify:

- stream.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com/video.mp4 - should give AccessDenied
- signed_distribution.cloudfront.net/video.mp4 - should give MissingKey (because the URL is not signed)
- basic_distribution.cloudfront.net/video.mp4 - should work fine

The tests will have to be adjusted to work with your stream player, but the basic idea is that only the basic cloudfront url should work.

**6 - Create a keypair for CloudFront**

I think the only way to do this is through Amazon's web site.  Go into your AWS "Account" page and click on the "Security Credentials" link.  Click on the "Key Pairs" tab then click "Create a New Key Pair".  This will generate a new key pair for you and automatically download a private key file (pk-xxxxxxxxx.pem).  Keep the key file safe and private.  Also note down the "Key Pair ID" from amazon as we will need it in the next step.

**7 - Generate some URLs in Python**

As of boto version 2.0 there does not seem to be any support for generating signed CloudFront URLs.  Python does not include RSA encryption routines in the standard library so we will have to use an additional library.  I've used M2Crypto in this example.

For a non-streaming distribution, you must use the full cloudfront URL as the resource, however for streaming we only use the object name of the video file.  See the code below for a full example of generating a URL which only lasts for 5 minutes.

This code is based loosely on the PHP example code provided by Amazon in the CloudFront documentation.

```
from M2Crypto import EVP
import base64
import time

def aws_url_base64_encode(msg):
    msg_base64 = base64.b64encode(msg)
    msg_base64 = msg_base64.replace('+', '-')
    msg_base64 = msg_base64.replace('=', '_')
    msg_base64 = msg_base64.replace('/', '~')
    return msg_base64

def sign_string(message, priv_key_string):
    key = EVP.load_key_string(priv_key_string)
    key.reset_context(md='sha1')
    key.sign_init()
    key.sign_update(str(message))
    signature = key.sign_final()
    return signature

def create_url(url, encoded_signature, key_pair_id, expires):
    signed_url = "%(url)s?Expires=%(expires)s&Signature=%(encoded_signature)s&Key-Pair-Id=%(key_pair_id)s" % {
            'url':url,
            'expires':expires,
            'encoded_signature':encoded_signature,
            'key_pair_id':key_pair_id,
            }
    return signed_url

def get_canned_policy_url(url, priv_key_string, key_pair_id, expires):
    #we manually construct this policy string to ensure formatting matches signature
    canned_policy = '{"Statement":[{"Resource":"%(url)s","Condition":{"DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":%(expires)s}}}]}' % {'url':url, 'expires':expires}

    #now base64 encode it (must be URL safe)
    encoded_policy = aws_url_base64_encode(canned_policy)
    #sign the non-encoded policy
    signature = sign_string(canned_policy, priv_key_string)
    #now base64 encode the signature (URL safe as well)
    encoded_signature = aws_url_base64_encode(signature)

    #combine these into a full url
    signed_url = create_url(url, encoded_signature, key_pair_id, expires);

    return signed_url

def encode_query_param(resource):
    enc = resource
    enc = enc.replace('?', '%3F')
    enc = enc.replace('=', '%3D')
    enc = enc.replace('&', '%26')
    return enc


#Set parameters for URL
key_pair_id = "APKAIAZCZRKVIO4BQ" #from the AWS accounts page
priv_key_file = "cloudfront-pk.pem" #your private keypair file
resource = 'video.mp4' #your resource (just object name for streaming videos)
expires = int(time.time()) + 300 #5 min

#Create the signed URL
priv_key_string = open(priv_key_file).read()
signed_url = get_canned_policy_url(resource, priv_key_string, key_pair_id, expires)

#Flash player doesn't like query params so encode them
enc_url = encode_query_param(signed_url)
print(enc_url)
```

**8 - Try out the URLs**

Hopefully you should now have a working URL which looks something like this:

```
video.mp4%3FExpires%3D1309979985%26Signature%3DMUNF7pw1689FhMeSN6JzQmWNVxcaIE9mk1x~KOudJky7anTuX0oAgL~1GW-ON6Zh5NFLBoocX3fUhmC9FusAHtJUzWyJVZLzYT9iLyoyfWMsm2ylCDBqpy5IynFbi8CUajd~CjYdxZBWpxTsPO3yIFNJI~R2AFpWx8qp3fs38Yw_%26Key-Pair-Id%3DAPKAIAZRKVIO4BQ
```

Put this into your js and you should have something which looks like this (from the PHP example in Amazon's CloudFront documentation):

```
var so_canned = new SWFObject('http://location.domname.com/~jvngkhow/player.swf','mpl','640','360','9');
    so_canned.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
    so_canned.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
    so_canned.addParam('wmode','opaque');
    so_canned.addVariable('file','video.mp4%3FExpires%3D1309979985%26Signature%3DMUNF7pw1689FhMeSN6JzQmWNVxcaIE9mk1x~KOudJky7anTuX0oAgL~1GW-ON6Zh5NFLBoocX3fUhmC9FusAHtJUzWyJVZLzYT9iLyoyfWMsm2ylCDBqpy5IynFbi8CUajd~CjYdxZBWpxTsPO3yIFNJI~R2AFpWx8qp3fs38Yw_%26Key-Pair-Id%3DAPKAIAZRKVIO4BQ');
    so_canned.addVariable('streamer','rtmp://s3nzpoyjpct.cloudfront.net/cfx/st');
    so_canned.write('canned');
```

---

**Summary**

As you can see, not very easy!  boto v2 will help a lot setting up the distribution.  I will find out if it's possible to get some URL generation code in there as well to improve this great library!

Comment: This is a great start. I can barely wait for the second half!

Comment: Just to reiterate, now you've finished the post, this is really great. I'm shocked at how pathetic the web UI is and how much heavy lifting they expect users to do to accomplish simple, advertised features. I'll try this tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: Well. Hooray! Permissions set and tested, streaming URL generated, working player, Oli happy. I will add that for some players --JW Player in my case-- you have to remove the extension of the file from the filename so `video.flv%3...` becomes `video%3...`. No idea why it needs that or why it even works... But there you go. Bounty well earned.

Comment: Thanks Oli!  Glad to hear it worked well for you.  And thanks for starting me off on StackOverflow!

Comment: Nice, one of the the most comprehensive SO answers I've seen. Thanks

Comment: Could something like this be reworked to prevent unauthorized referrers (meaning "not my servers") from accessing or linking to images and content being served by AWS Cloudfront (the Amazon CDN)?  I've been trying to find a way to stop hotlinking and bots / crawlers from running up the bill we pay for the AWS Cloudfront CDN.  Should add that we're using a Custom Origin (servers are in a colo) and **not** hosting from EC2, S3, etc.

Comment: S3 supports restrictions based on HTTP Referer however cloudfront currently only supports time and source IP address.  For hotlinking, generating time-expiring URLs as described here should work.  Anything that links directly to your content will stop working after a few minutes.  For crawlers, I recommend a robots.txt

Comment: Is there a recent example / instructions using create_signed_url method in [Boto 2.5.2 ?](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/cloudfront.html) The link to the blog post is broken. Could you please fix the link? Thanks

Comment: @ipegasus Sorry about that - Fixed! The 2.0 series of boto has been out long enough so I'll move the docs into here shortly.

Comment: @josh-crozier The script in step 7 seems to be over-encoding the URL. To get this to work for me, I had to comment our these three lines, so that Amazon sees the query values: 
    #enc = enc.replace('?', '%3F')
    #enc = enc.replace('=', '%3D')
    #enc = enc.replace('&', '%26')

Answer (score 3):

> In Python, what's the easiest way of generating an expiring URL for a file. I have boto installed but I don't see how to get a file from a streaming distribution.

You can generate a expiring signed-URL for the resource. Boto3 documentation has a [nice example solution](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/cloudfront.html#examples) for that:

> ```
> import datetime
>
> from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
> from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
> from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
> from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
> from botocore.signers import CloudFrontSigner
>
>
> def rsa_signer(message):
>     with open('path/to/key.pem', 'rb') as key_file:
>         private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
>             key_file.read(), 
>             password=None,
>             backend=default_backend()
>         )
>     signer = private_key.signer(padding.PKCS1v15(), hashes.SHA1())
>     signer.update(message)
>     return signer.finalize()
>
> key_id = 'AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE'
> url = 'http://d2949o5mkkp72v.cloudfront.net/hello.txt'
> expire_date = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1)
>
> cloudfront_signer = CloudFrontSigner(key_id, rsa_signer)
>
> # Create a signed url that will be valid until the specfic expiry date
> # provided using a canned policy.
> signed_url = cloudfront_signer.generate_presigned_url(
>     url, date_less_than=expire_date)
> print(signed_url)
> ```

Comment: I am getting an error in the line `private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
            key_file.read(), 
            password=None,
            backend=default_backend()
        ) `

saying that `UnsupportedAlgorithm: This backend does not support this key serialization.`

Any idea why that is. I am loading the pem file as per the example.

Take a look at this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251810/unsupportedalgorithm-this-backend-does-not-support-this-key-serialization-py)