# How to set up "Cloudfront Access Origin Identity?"

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, streaming, amazon-cloudfront

I want to set up secure cloudfront streaming using this plugin:

http://flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/cloudfront/index.html

However, I don't know how to perform the second step ("Create your Cloudfront Access Origin Identity") because I have no idea what a "Cloudfront Access Origin Identity" is. Is it just a user?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the following docs

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/HowToPrivateContent.html

The docs explains how to setup origin access indentity + signed urls.

Comment: I'm in the same boat, and unfortunately this document is confusing. There's no actual example of using the Origin Access Identity in conjunction with the link, just confusing things about private links and signatures.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a useful stack overflow answer that covers the whole process end to end:

[Getting started with secure AWS CloudFront streaming with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549787/getting-started-with-secure-aws-cloudfront-streaming-with-python/6590986#6590986)