# UnsupportedAlgorithm: This backend does not support this key serialization. - Python cryptography load_pem_private_key

Tags: python, google-app-engine, boto3, pem, python-cryptography

I am trying to generate signed urls for AWS Cloudfront based on the example [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudfront.html#examples). On the line

```
private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
        key_file.read(),
        password=None,
        backend=default_backend()
    )
```

I get the error `UnsupportedAlgorithm: This backend does not support this key serialization.` The full trace is as below:

```
File "command_util.py", line 98, in rsa_signer
    backend=default_backend()  
File "runtime/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization.py", line 20, in load_pem_private_key
    return backend.load_pem_private_key(data, password)
File "runtime/cryptography/hazmat/backends/multibackend.py", line 286, in load_pem_private_key
    _Reasons.UNSUPPORTED_SERIALIZATION
UnsupportedAlgorithm: This backend does not support this key serialization.
```

On reading the docs it says that the exception occurs because of the following:

```
cryptography.exceptions.UnsupportedAlgorithm – the serialized key is of a type that is not supported by the backend or if 
the key is encrypted with a symmetric cipher that is not supported by the backend.
```

The PEM file given starts with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and ends with `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` .

I am using google appengine sdk while developing this application.

I need help understanding this error message and how to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the python cryptography library cannot be used with google appengine(GAE) as this library needs to have C extensions and you cannot install C extensions in GAE. You can only use pure python packages.

Comment: Nice, i was tracking the question.